# Previously annotated identifier with @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) must still be annotated: AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

Tags: aura-enabled, cacheable

I am getting this error when I tried to remove the `cacheable=true` from the below method.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
global static boolean packageNotExpired() {
    /// my code;
}
```

> Previously annotated identifier with @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) must
> still be annotated: AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

Comment: If you are working on managed packages and this classes is already added to package, global methods cannot be removed and only [deprecated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_deprecated.htm)

Comment: I recommend against the use of deprecation. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287327/deprecate-or-remove-an-apex-invocable-action-from-process-builder-in-a-managed-p/287329#287329) for my reasoning.

Comment: thanks, @PhilW I visited that post, it is very helpful, after knowing this I would be careful while deprecating any code.

Comment: Great thanks for the insights @Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note it is global and removing cacheable from the global method would impact subscriber code - that code may be using this via a wire, which requires the result to be cacheable. (I am assuming you have this code in a managed package of some form, hence the use of "global".)

I suggest you add a separate uncached method that invokes the same processing as the cacheable one. The second method can even directly call the first one since the cacheable annotation only impacts client communications:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
global static boolean packageNotExpired() {
    /// my code;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean packageIsNotExpired() {
    return ThisClass.packageNotExpired();
}
```

It is worth noting that the use of global access modifier should always be minimized.