# Packaging a custom label as unprotected

Tags: managed-package, customlabel

Is it considered against best practices if I package a custom label as unprotected? The requirement is that the subscriber org is trying to access the value from a custom label from the managed package. This custom label is treated as a flag in the system. I'm assuming once marked as unprotected it cannot be protected again.

**Edit:**
The scenario is my managed package supports multi-language, one of the custom labels `User_code` has a numeric value, 0 is the default value. When translation is enabled admin can create translated values for the desired language let's say French for which the `User_code` value will be 1. This custom label is referenced in the code. In the subscriber org, the user is trying to reference the label in a formula field but it unable to do so since it's unprotected. This has already been built into the package so I can't change the way it works right now, but, open to suggestions.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is correct, you can not make it protected anymore, nor delete it. But then it can be used in unmanaged code

Comment: So it's not developer deletable? Would you recommend that? @kurunve

Comment: Use of a custom label as a flag is a bad idea. Custom labels are intended for localization and may have different values added to them for different languages via the translation workbench. If you want a "setting" then you should be using Custom Metadata Types or (if you want to use the older solution) Custom Settings. Either approach would allow you to have settings dedicated to specific users if that was necessary.

Comment: It is used for Translations and so it would have different values based on the user locale. @PhilW

Comment: So "This custom label is treated as a flag in the system" doesn't mean you have code that checks if it is "true" or "false", for example?

Comment: btw, I believe in essence you will have the same experience as you do for layouts or unprotected custom metadata type instances included in the package; the unprotected values are installed on first installation, but any subsequent updates will be ignored.

Comment: @PhilW it has numeric values starting from '0' which represents English and yes it is checked in the code. 

So If I were to mark the label as unprotected it will not be accessible by the subscriber org as originally it was packaged as protected?

Comment: If you really need to protect the custom label, you could encapsulate accessing the protected custom label via global apex code and deprecate apex code in later versions when needed (although by doing this, subscribers on older version would still continue to use it). As far as access modifier specification is concerned for custom labels, it should up to the author to decide based on the confidentiality of the label.

Comment: I think you should expand the question to explain the business case of what you are doing; someone might be able to recommend a completely different and more appropriate approach. From what you've said so far, I believe what you're doing doesn't really align with the purpose of labels and could easily end up in a mess.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, beware of Apex deprecation. See [this posting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287327/deprecate-or-remove-an-apex-invocable-action-from-process-builder-in-a-managed-p/287329#287329) for more detail.

Comment: I have added more context to the question @PhilW

Comment: OK, so I assume you are trying to work around https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IUIN

Comment: If so I guess the approach should work as long as you unprotect the label. You will be stuck with having it exposed in your package and will not be able to change the packaged value in future without also requiring a manual process for upgrade installs.