# Evolve global classes in 1GP Managed packages (e.g. add method)

Tags: managed-package, isv, global-methods, 1gp-package

I have a `1GP` Managed Packaged with **Released Versions** (but no customers only Dev orgs) and it contains a `global` class with various `abstract` methods that subscribers could override.

```
global with sharing abstract class MyApi {

    // ABSTRACT
    
    global abstract void anOperation(...);
    global abstract void anotherOperation(...);

    ...
}
```

Now I tried adding another global abstract method but it fails to deploy in the Packaging org with:

> `Cannot add new final methods to virtual or abstract classes`

Until now, I didn't know if this seemingly undocumented restriction that you can not extend global classes by adding more restrictions.

**Question: What are my options to mitigate that?**

1. Can I leverage @deprecated in any way?
2. Should I simply kill this class and invent a new one? Including refactoring all my code?
3. Should I switch to 2GP? Not sure if that is even possible?
4. Is there other ways I am currently not thinking of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot add a new abstract method to a published global class since this would invalidate any existing implementations/extensions of that class; they would be incomplete.

You can, however, add new virtual method(s) and provide stub implementation(s) of the new method(s) so any existing implementation/extension classes are still complete.

If that is enough, go for it.

A word of warning around the suggestion of using `@deprecate`... don't. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287327/deprecate-or-remove-an-apex-invocable-action-from-process-builder-in-a-managed-p/287329#287329) for why.

It is also worth noting that global interfaces impose even more strict requirements; once released these cannot be modified at all. This is, again, to prevent existing implementations from being made incomplete (missing implementations of added methods).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem very simply by making the new method `virtual` instead:

```
global with sharing abstract class MyApi {

    // ABSTRACT
    
    global abstract void anOperation(...);
    global abstract void anotherOperation(...);

    // VIRTUAL 
    // To not break exisiting handlers just virtual (see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/410879/256)
    global virtual Rules aThirdOperation(...) {
        throw new ApplicationException('aThirdOperation() method not implemented by the current implementation.');
    }
   
    ...
}
```